# Array acting quite oddly in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

Ok I have a simple for loop in Javascript that will create an array of numbers, I need to do this so I can then swap them around to create random positions. But anyways here is the code

```
            var aliveMonsters = [];
    var deadMonsters = 0;
    for( var i = 0; i < monsterAmount; i++ )
    {
        if( monsters[i].hp > 0 )
        {
            var place = i - deadMonsters;
            var placed = i - deadMonsters;
            aliveMonsters[place] = placed;
        }
        else
        {
            deadMonsters -= 1;
        }
        //console.log(i);
    }
            console.log(aliveMonsters);
```

when all 3 monsters are alive this is printed out

```
[0, 1, 2]
```

Which is correct, but when one of them dies (0, 1 or even 2), the array then becomes this

```
[0, 3: 3]
```

this code is called everytime a player makes a move and it works fine until a monster is dead (HP is set to 0). Can anyone see why this is happening?

Here is a picture, dont worry about the array that displays undefined.
[image]

Comment: Did you mean to type `[0, 3, 3]` instead of `[0, 3: 3]`?

Comment: Nope [0, 3: 3] is what I am getting

Comment: `[0, 3: 3] => SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Comment: Nope that is what I am getting in the console in google chrome

Comment: @Canvas Are you sure? That doesn't make any sense. Are you absoultely sure that they are `[]` brackets, and not `{}`? You could add a screenshot in your question for clarification.

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: This makes no sense at all! have you tried the same code in a different browser?

Comment: @Canvas Is that a beta version? I thought the latest was `29.0.1547.57`

Comment: Should it be `deadMonsters += 1`?

Comment: LOL Explosion I think you may have it lol, let me check

Comment: @Doorknob no, .62 is the latest patch release for Chrome 29

Comment: Please don't put the answer inside your question. There is an "answers" section....

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo in a specific piece of code. It is not likely to help future visitors to the site.

Answer (score 0):

Putting deadMonsters += 1 corrected the error